# Как распарсить псевдо-xml?

Tags: xml, android, java, синтаксический-анализ

Приходит вот такой всевдо хмл. Иногда позиций по 20-30. Не понимаю, как подступиться. Читаю про парсинг и везде написано, что нужно по тегам ориентироваться, а тут имеет значение номер строки.

```
<ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeInfo>
<ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeContactInfo>
88000000000
+74950000000
client_info@mail.ru
http://site.ru/
https://mb.site.ru/
<ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeContactInfo>
<ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeInfo>
```

Если приходит много инфы, например список офисов, принимает вид примерно вот такой:

```
<ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeInfo>
<ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeContactInfo>
88000000000
+74951110001
client_info@mail.ru
http://site.ru/
https://mb.site.ru/
</ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeContactInfo>
<ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeContactInfo>
88000000000
+74951110001
client_info@mail.ru
http://site.ru/
https://mb.site.ru/
</ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeContactInfo>
<ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeContactInfo>
88000000000
+74951110001
client_info@mail.ru
http://site.ru/
https://mb.site.ru/
</ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeContactInfo>
<ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeInfo>
```

Comment: @Garf1eld, попробуйте очистить и пересобрать проект.
А вообще, я советую вам сделать так:

    resp = "<data>" + resp + "</data>";

Лично у меня JSoup не мог работать без коренного элемента.

Comment: @SuperCreeper сначала подумал, что это ошибка связанная с работой кода. Разобрался, это некорректно jar добавил.

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException
В строке `Elements eData = doc.getElementsByTag("ru.sim...");`

Comment: @Garf1eld, тогда попробуйте парсить вот [так][http://stackoverflow.com/a/9947639/3856132].

Comment: Что-то никак...

Answer (score 3):

[@Garf1eld](/users/18710/garf1eld), попробуйте библиотеку JSoup. Разработчики недавно научили её работать с xml. Сначала получите нужные данные:

```
Connection mConnection = Jsoup.connect(URL);
mConnection.method(Connection.Method.GET);
Connection.Response mResponse = mConnection.execute();
```

Потом начинайте парсинг:

```
Elements eData = mResponce.parse.getElementsByTag("ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeInfo");
for (Element eInfo : eData)
{
    Element eContact = eInfo.getElementsByTag("ru.simple.abcd.mobile.SomeContactInfo").get(0);
    String sContactData = eContact.toString();
    //Можно также вызвать eContact.text();
    String[] sContent = sContactData.split("\n");
    //И обрабатываете дальше
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, тут просто будет два этапа:

1. Парсим как XML, получаем массив, в котором каждый элемент - содержимое тега.
2. Парсим каждый элемент массива, разбивая по whitespace-символам (или строго по \n) и получаем для каждого элемента массив необходимых данных.